# Error while posting jquery error to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery ajax POST everywhere in application.  Below is a sample ajax post. The content type is set based on the `data`. Content Type could be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` or `application/json; charset=utf-8`

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: somedata,
        url: 'someurl',
        contentType: 'somecontenttype',
        processData: true,
        cache: true,
    })
    .done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       //dosomething here    
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {            
         logger.log({ message: jqXHR, code: "Error" });
    })
```

The above method works fine.

However, for any reason, if the POST fails, i want to log that error to server. So in `fail` handler i am logging `jqXHR` to server. I have created a logger that `POST` object to server. like below

```
var logger = (function ($) {
    var module = {};

    module.log = function (obj) {
        try {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: obj,
                url: '/jslog',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            })               
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error('JS error report submission failed.');
            })
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.error('JS error report submission failed.');
        }
    }

    return module;

})(jQuery);
```

*Note that the code is wrapped inside `try-catch` so if the logging to server failed we just log generic error in console.*

**ISSUE**
When `logger` tries to POST obj to server. I get below exception. The error occurs before actual POST so request never comes to server.

> Unable to get property 'toLowerCase' of undefined or null reference
>
> "TypeError: Unable to get property 'toLowerCase' of undefined or null
>   reference\n   at jqXHR.getResponseHeader
>   (http://localhost:58641/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js:9523:7)\n   at add
>   (http://localhost:58641/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js:10073:4)\n   at
>   buildParams
>   (http://localhost:58641/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js:10061:3)\n   at
>   buildParams
>   (http://localhost:58641/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js:10055:4)\n   at
>   jQuery.param
>   (http://localhost:58641/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js:10095:4)\n   at ajax
>   (http://localhost:58641/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js:9612:4)\n   at
>   module.log (http://localhost:58641/Scripts/logger.js:5:13)\n   at
>   module.showError (http://localhost:58641/Scripts/common.js:164:13)\n
>   at Anonymous function
>   (http://localhost:58641/Scripts/common.js:322:13)\n   at fire
>   (http://localhost:58641/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js:3232:6)"

**UPDATE1**
I changed my logger to POST object as string. So i `stringify` the object on client side during POST, and remove content type

```
 module.log = function (obj) {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { log: JSON.stringify(obj) },
            url: '/jslog'
        })
        .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error('JS error report submission failed.');
        })
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.error('JS error report submission failed.');
    }
```

It POST the string to server but server rejects its with error
`A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client`
Thats because `jqXHR.responseText` has `html`

The server side code is ASP.NET MVC

Comment: when you debug, does it make it to the console.error in the javascript? If it doesn't, it looks like its something in the controller where you have a variable set to be read as toLowerCase but there needs to be something there to read, which is why the error is coming up saying it can't read a null result

Comment: You're trying to send the entire jqXHR object via ajax, you probably want `logger.log({ message: jqXHR.responseText, code: "Error" });`

Comment: it also might be easier to store the message on the server side and do the try/catch there storing the message in a variable and calling it in the javascript

Comment: If you want to send JSON, you need to call `JSON.stringify()` on the object. jQuery doesn't do this automatically, it always uses URL-encoding.

Comment: You are correct i forgot to stringify object

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery ajax method will, when arranging the data for submission, interrogate the object and, as it works through the members, will invoke functions to obtain values:

```
jQuery.param = function( a, traditional ) {
    var prefix,
        s = [],
        add = function( key, value ) {

            // If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
            value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value );
            s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( value );
        };

     [...]
```

And so, if you are sending in an object that also has the `jqXHR` object as a member or the `jqXHR` object itself, it will eventually come across the `getResponseHeader` member and attempt to invoke it with no parameter resulting in the `Unable to get property toLowerCase of undefined or null` error.

Best bet as mentioned in the comments is to stringify the object being submitted to the logger.